# JCS 2.2 - How to set max size of memory/index disk cache?

Tags: java, eclipse, caching, apache-commons, jcs

I'm using JCS to create a cache with LRU Memory Cache and the Indexed Disk Cache. I realize that there are properties like MaxObjects and maxKeySize that allow me to set the *amount* of items in a certain cache, but I'm wondering if JCS allows me to set the size in terms of how many KB, MB, GB, etc. each cache uses overall?

The Apache Commons JCS site references a KeySize attribute for the indexed disk cache [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/IndexedDiskAuxCache.html), but when I try to set that attribute in my cache.ccf, I'm told that there's "No such property [keySize] in org.apache.commons.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCacheAttributes."

Does anyone know if JCS allows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2.2, the property for disk cache size limiting appears to be `jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.MaxKeySize`.
Example configuration:

```
jcs.default=JC
jcs.auxiliary.DC=org.apache.commons.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCacheFactory
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes=org.apache.commons.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCacheAttributes
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.DiskPath=cache
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.DiskLimitType=SIZE
#Disk limit size in KB- 1 GB
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.MaxKeySize=1000000
```

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell there's no parallel for the in-memory cache.